# Pushing to remote gitlab Git repository from appveyor build

Tags: gitlab, access-token, appveyor

I try to follow the steps described here https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/git-push/

I got stuck to Add access token to credential store for gitlab I tried `ps: Add-Content "$HOME\.git-credentials" "https://$($env:access_token):x-oauth-basic@gitlab.com` but this doesn't work. I got `fatal: Authentication failed for https://gitlab.com`
My appveyor yml file looks like the follwoing

```
branches:
  only:
    - master

environment:
  access_token:
    # EDIT the encrypted version of your GitHub access token
    secure: ********************************

on_success:
  - git config --global credential.helper store
  # EDIT your Git email and name
  - git config --global user.email *****@l***.com
  - git config --global user.name As**** A***
  - ps: Add-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\.git-credentials" "https://$($env:access_token):x-oauth-basic@gitlab.com`n"
  - git checkout -f master
  - git clean  -d  -f .
  - xcopy ..\output output /E /Y /I

  # EDIT the origin of your repository - have to reset it here because AppVeyor pulls from SSH, but GitHub won't accept SSH pushes
  - git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/****/project.git
  - git add .
  - git commit -a -m "Commit from AppVeyor to gitlab"
  - git push
```

What to change to make it woking for gitlab?

Comment: If I hardcoded git remote set-url origin https://oauth2:<mytoken>@gitlab.com/myuser/myrepo.git it works.but i want to use encrypted appveyor  secure token

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-NoNewLine` to the end of the command setting `.git-credentials`:

```
  - ps: Add-Content -Path "$HOME\.git-credentials" -Value "https://oauth2:$($env:access_token)@gitlab.com`n" -NoNewline
```

That example changed recently as Git 2.26.2 tightened security.

Also note, I've changed the value to pass credentials as in your example that worked: `https://oauth2:$($env:access_token)@gitlab.com`n`

Comment: Do you mean  I've changed the value to pass credentials as in your example that worked to git remote set-url origin https://oauth2:$($env:access_token)@gitlab.com/****/****.git

Comment: My guess if `oauth2:<token>` worked for you then it should be the same in credentials file. The essential thing there, though, is `-NoNewline` at the end.